# Video format using LVDS signalling

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, serial, lvds, tft

I have a 3.1inch TFT.

I have the below two pins

[image]

Can someone tell me what does the 2 pins do?

My questions :

1. So, I can select either 6 bit or 8 bit for the whole communication and can't change in-between, right? So, I should go completely with 6-bits or 8-bits with no changes?
2. I can choose only one format for the data, right ? But not alternate between both in-between ?

Answer (score 0):

Pin 2 selects either [JEIDA data format or VESA data format](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snla014a/snla014a.pdf?ts=1611733988320&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.startpage.com%252F#:%7E:text=The%20JEIDA%20format%20is%20very,7%5D%20without%20any%20user%20intervention.).

> *So, I can select either 6 bit or 8 bit for the whole communication and
> can't change in-between, right? So, I should go completely with 6-bits
> or 8-bits with no changes?*

You'll need to read the data sheet. You could always try it and see!

> *I can choose only one format for the data, right ? But not alternate
> between both in-between ?*

You'll need to read the data sheet.

Comment: Thank you. What about six bit and 8 bit?

Comment: Could you also advice on which data format to use ? JEIDA or VESA? Which is bettter?

Comment: I can't advise on which format is better.

Comment: Ok but there is not much information in the datasheet regarding the bits. Could you please help me a little more with it

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Can we discuss in chat

Comment: Have you looked at the TI document I linked?

Comment: Yes, I checked.

Comment: You will use the bitness and data format on the display that matches what the other device is sending to the display. You really don't have to be wiggling these pins every few milliseconds or so, it will be fixed for the lifetime of the hardware.

Comment: @newbie - if you still need help you should link to the data sheet of the display.